# Python - iteratring over a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that is generated using a series of `for` loops.  The result looks something like this:

```
{
'item1': {
    'attribute1': [3],
    'attribute2': [2],
    'attribute3': [False],
    },
'item2': {
    'attribute1': [2, 5, 2],
    'attribute2': [3, 2, 8],
    'attribute3': [False, 7, False],
    },
'item3': {
    'attribute1': [8],
    'attribute2': [4],
    'attribute3': [False],
    },
}
```

The `False` shows in `'attribute3'` is a result of passing an empty value into the `item`s initial state.  Then `'item2'` is updated through two more iterations.

What I'd like to do is have the lists for each attribute the same length such that the desired output is:

```
{
'item1': {
    'attribute1': [3, False, False],
    'attribute2': [2, False, False],
    'attribute3': [False, False, False],
    },
'item2': {
    'attribute1': [2, 5, 2],
    'attribute2': [3, 2, 8],
    'attribute3': [False, 7, False],
    },
'item3': {
    'attribute1': [8, False, False],
    'attribute2': [4, False, False],
    'attribute3': [False, False, False],
    },
}
```

For reference - the code for an initial entry checks to make sure that `item_desc` is unique and if so generate a new entry - - it looks something like this:

```
record.update({item_desc: {
    'attribute1':[],
    'attribute2':[],
    'attribute3':[],
    }})
for key, value in [
    ('attribute1', value1),
    ('attribute2', value2),
    ('attribute3', value3)]:
    record[item_desc][key].append(value)
```

If the `'item_desc'` is not unique, then the `'for key, value in...'` is run again against the non-unique `'item_desc'` and the new attribute values are appended to the existing item.

What have I tried...  well, I tried iterating through the "record" object when a unique item is found and append a False value using something like this:

```
for item in record:
    for key in ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3']:
    record[item][key].append(False)
```

But (i) it doesn't solve for adding a `False` for subsequent unique items and (ii) I need the lists to stay in order - so it doesn't do me any good to simply iterate through everything at the end and force to a given number of elements for the list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {
    'item1': {
        'attribute1': [3], 
        'attribute2': [2], 
        'attribute3': [False]}, 
    'item2': {
        'attribute1': [2, 5, 2], 
        'attribute2': [3, 2, 8], 
        'attribute3': [False, 7, False]}, 
    'item3': {
        'attribute1': [8], 
        'attribute2': [4], 
        'attribute3': [False]}}
adjust = max(len(max([c['attribute1'], c['attribute2'], c['attribute3']])) for c in d.values())
new_d = {a:{c:j+([False]*(adjust-len(j))) for c, j in b.items()} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{
'item1': {
    'attribute1': [3, False, False], 
    'attribute2': [2, False, False], 
    'attribute3': [False, False, False]}, 
'item2': {
    'attribute1': [2, 5, 2], 
    'attribute2': [3, 2, 8], 
    'attribute3': [False, 7, False]}, 
'item3': {
    'attribute1': [8, False, False], 
    'attribute2': [4, False, False], 
    'attribute3': [False, False, False]}}
```

Comment: This is what i'm looking for - but it has a static max list length (e.g., 3).  How would you make this dynamic so that it would look at `d` and adjust the `(3-len(j)` such that the 3 is the longest list for any attribute within `d`?

Answer (score 3):

The dict comprehension is a good solution and pure python.

Just for a matter of options, you can also use a library such as `pandas`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
max_ = df.max().str.len().max() # max length (in this case, 3)
df.transform(lambda x: [z + [False]*(max_ - len(z)) for z in x]).to_dict()
```

outputs

```
{'item1': 
    {'attribute1': [3, False, False],
     'attribute2': [2, False, False],
     'attribute3': [False, False, False]
    },
 'item2': 
    {'attribute1': [2, 5, 2],
     'attribute2': [3, 2, 8],
     'attribute3': [False, 7, False]
     },
 'item3': 
    {'attribute1': [8, False, False],
     'attribute2': [4, False, False],
     'attribute3': [False, False, False]
    }
}
```